# resize image without using image_lib in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

my problem is I want to re size my image, im searching about how codeigniter re size the image but I found that all of them are using the image_lib(). I am not using image_lib() so I confused on how to re size the image without using image_lib()..

here is my **ci_controller**

```
public function fileUpload()
       {

    $title =  $this->input->post('title');
          $attachment_file=$_FILES["attachment_file"];
          $output_dir = "images/header/";
          $fileName = $_FILES["attachment_file"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachment_file"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName);

    $this->person->save($title, $fileName,'slider');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to download and configure 3rd party image_resize libraries when CI provides inbuilt libraries for that!!....If you want to do that just follow below steps:

STEP 1: import library using this single line...

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
```

STEP 2:As per your code now,make changes as below

```
    public function fileUpload()
       {

    $title =  $this->input->post('title');
    $sourcePath = $_FILES["attachment_file"]['tmp_name']; //  source path of the file;
    $new_img = time(). '_' .$_FILES["attachment_file"]['name'];
    $targetPath = 'images/header/' . $new_img; // Target path where file is to be stored
    move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath); // Moving Uploaded file


     $config_resize['image_library'] = 'gd2';
     $config_resize['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
     $config_resize['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
     $config_resize['master_dim'] = 'height';
     $config_resize['quality'] = "100%";
     $config_resize['source_image'] = $targetPath;
     $config_resize['height'] = 60;
     $config_resize['width'] = 60;
     $config_resize['thumb_marker'] = '';
     $config_resize['new_image'] = 'images/header/' . $new_img;
     $this->image_lib->initialize($config_resize);
     $this->image_lib->resize();

     $uploaded = TRUE;

    $this->person->save($title, $new_img ,'slider');

}
```

STEP 3: Thats all...it may require little modification as per your need.If any issue or you don't have any idea how the library works visit this link..

[Official ellislab guideline](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html)